# How to filter products dynamically with react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

I have been stuck on this for an entire day and still nowhere near achieving this.

I have a product with fields as follow

```
 products :[
  {
   brand :"Ray Band",
   size :"medium",
   price :250,
   ...others
},
{
   brand :"Okaley",
   size :"large",
   price :500,
   ...others
},
{
   brand :"Dior",
   size :"free size",
   price :475,
   ...others
}
]
```

I want to filter these products by providing certain fields. I want to filter them by using an object below.

```
 const filterFields ={
  brand :["rayband","okaley"],
  size :["free size"]
}
```

I want to filter the products by "brand" "ray band" or "okaley". Also their sizes will have to be "free size". I also want to add other keys and values dynamically by displaying checkbox. I also expect them to work properly without having to check if else manually.
How do I do that? I have tried a lot of different ways and nothing so far have worked since it includes a lot of nested forEachs.
Please someone help me here. I am also using React.js

Answer (score 3):

This way should work dynamically for any key name

```
const filtered = products.filter(product => {
 return Object.keys(filterFields).reduce((acc, filter) => {
    const filterValues = filterFields[filter];
    const productValue = product[filter];

    //This line defines what is your match
    const found = filterValues.find(fv => fv == productValue);

    return acc && found;
  }, true);
})
```

You should change the inner find as you want

Comment: I don't understand the code thoroughly but this works like a charm. Thanks a million.

Comment: What part didn't you understand? I guess it is the reduce, this reduce an array to a single value, in this case, a value that decides whether the product fit the filterFields or not. So, I applied this to the keys of the filterFields (the fields used by the user), reduceing to a single match or not match. 

Object.keys() get all the keys of an object.

Some docs may help you understand better.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Also 
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find  
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I don't understand the return value of acc && found. What does that actually return? I know found returns the product if it matches the filterValue, otherwise undefined. But what does the combination of acc && found return?

Comment: acc is the return value of previous elements in array, starting with true on the last line, so the acc represents the test result of keys already tested, and return acc && found is kind of..
if (otherKeysFilteredMatch && actualKeyTestedMatch).
As acc is boolean, found is implicitly converted to false when undefined and true in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hello please try this.

```
   const list = [
    {
      brand: "Ray Band",
      size: "medium",
      price: 250,
    },
    {
      brand: "Okaley",
      size: "large",
      price: 500,
    },
    {
      brand: "Dior",
      size: "free size",
      price: 475,
    },
  ];
  const filterFields = {
    brand: [],
    size: [],
  };

    list.forEach((l, index) => {
    if (!filterFields.brand.find((b) => b === l.brand)) {
      filterFields.brand.push(l.brand);
    }
    if (!filterFields.size.find((s) => s === l.size)) {
      filterFields.size.push(l.size);
    }

    // USING DYNAMIC KEYS
    let elementKeys = Object.keys(l);

    elementKeys.forEach((k) => {
      if (!filterFields[k]) {
        filterFields[k] = [];
      }
      if (!filterFields[k].find((field) => field === l[k])) {
        filterFields[k].push(l[k]);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log("filterFields", filterFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.filter()` method in this way:

```
products.filter(product => filterFields.brand.includes(product.brand) || filterFields.size.includes(product.size))
```

This means to filter the product which it's brand name is contained in the `filterField`'s brand array and also same for the size